# Webpack mix Laravel. Bundle array of files into same folder

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-5.6

So I'm using the `webpack.mix.js` file to compile all my js files. I have a this folder tree

```
assets
|--js
    |--datatables
        |--users.js
        |--countries.js
        |--taxes.js
        ...
```

and I want the same structure in my `public` folder.

What I'm doing right now is executing one line for each js file and telling where to put them.

```
.js('resources/assets/js/datatables/users.js', 'public/js/datatables')
.js('resources/assets/js/datatables/countries.js', 'public/js/datatables')
.js('resources/assets/js/datatables/taxes.js', 'public/js/datatables')
...
```

But the list is getting way too longer. **Is there a way to tell webpack to bundle a list of files in a specific folder?** I've tried to pass an array instead of a single file url but that doesn't work.

```
/** Does not work */
.js([
    'resources/assets/js/datatables/users.js',
    'resources/assets/js/datatables/countries.js',
    'resources/assets/js/datatables/taxes.js',
    ...
], 'public/js/datatables')
```

Comment: Except using `.js(` use `.scripts(....`.  `mix.scripts([ 'public/js/admin.js', 'public/js/dashboard.js' ], 'public/js/all.js`

Comment: No your specific use case does not seem to be supported by [`.js`](https://github.com/devanandb/webpack-mix/blob/master/docs/mixjs.md)

Comment: @mafortis I don't want all the files into one. I want them separate so I can import each one as I require them. But I guess it cannot be accomplished. Thank you anyway

Comment: In that way make each line as you do, run npm dev command, edit and run the command for next file (one by one)